# SQL Query to select parent hierarchy for a child

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a table (dim_factory_relation) which stored the child factory IDs and the parent factory id for each child factories in the below format.

```
FK_CHILD_FACTORY_ID   FK_PARENT_FACTORY_ID
65                      5
66                      5
5                      13
10                     13
13                     25
13                     40
30                     40
40                    100
71                     56
72                     56
56                    100
```

Now, if I pass the lower child factory, it should provide the list of parents till the top level. Eg. I'm passing 65 as a child factory. It has to give me

```
FK_PARENT_FACTORY_ID
5
13
25
40
100
```

Please help how to get this using Oracle SQLs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should show us what you tried and how it failed. Not ask for free source

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical-data+oracle or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query+oracle

Answer (score 3):

Use [`connect by prior`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

```
select FK_PARENT_FACTORY_ID
  from t
start with FK_CHILD_FACTORY_ID = 65
connect by prior FK_PARENT_FACTORY_ID=FK_CHILD_FACTORY_ID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                   FK_PARENT_FACTORY_ID
---------------------------------------
                                      5
                                     13
                                     25
                                     40
                                    100
```

Comment: I would probably include LEVEL in the SELECT - the result set has no order, and one would assume (even if the OP doesn't realize it) that the relationships between the ancestors are relevant to whatever problem this is meant to solve.